# Extract text immediately before double colons

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this:

```
text <- "This is some text::stuff. Look, there's some::more. And here::is some more."
```

I would like to extract the words before the double colons. To do this, I use `gregexpr` to match for alpha-numerics immediately before double colons:

```
m <- gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]*::", text)
```

Then, I call `regmatches` to pull out this text, `unlist` the result to a vector, and finally strip out the double colons with `gsub`.

```
gsub("::", "", unlist(regmatches(text, m)))
#[1] "text" "some" "here"
```

This is the desired result, but relies on four function calls. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookahead and `str_extract_all` to do it all in one go:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text, "\\w+(?=::)")[[1]]
[1] "text" "some" "here"
```

Comment: And to clarify for others wondering (as I did): `\w` refers to word characters (e.g., 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _, etc.) and, as Wiktor explains in another answer, `(?=...)` is a non-consuming lookahead construct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
m <- gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]+(?=::)", text, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uhDEOP/1). Here, `[[:alnum:]]+(?=::)` matches one or more letters or digits and then checks if they are immediately followed with two colons without consuming the colons, since the `(?=...)` is a non-consuming lookahead construct.

Mind the `perl=TRUE` argument becomes obligatory here since the default TRE regex engine does not allow lookaround use. `perl=TRUE` enables the PCRE regex engine, and it allows both lookbehinds and lookaheads.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/1l7P83):

```r
text <- "This is some text::stuff. Look, there's some::more. And here::is some more."
m <- gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]+(?=::)", text, perl=TRUE)
unlist(regmatches(text, m))
## => [1] "text" "some" "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a capture group instead of lookarounds, and repeat `[[:alnum:]]+` 1 or more times to prevent matching empty strings

```
library(stringr)

text <- "This is some text::stuff. Look, there's some::more. And here::is some more."
str_match_all(text, "([[:alnum:]]+)::")[[1]][,2]
```

Output

```
[1] "text" "some" "here"
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/c9AfYE)